# Indexing columns to make a MySQL query faster

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this query here that I am trying to make more efficient as it is taking an extremely long amount of time, about 40s on 3 million records.

The query basically takes X amount of rows per company and turns them into columns for a given existing column.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b88/9)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @sql1 = NULL;
SET @sql2 = NULL;
SET @sql3 = NULL;
SET @sql4 = NULL;
SET @sql5 = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max(case when year = ', year, ' then experience_rate end) AS `', year, '-Pen`' ) ORDER BY year ) INTO @sql1 FROM spooner_pec;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max(case when year = ', year, ' then mco_name end) AS `', year, '-MCO`' ) ORDER BY year ) INTO @sql2 FROM spooner_pec;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max(case when year = ', year, ' then premium_range end) AS `', year, '-Prem`' ) ORDER BY year ) INTO @sql3 FROM spooner_pec;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max(case when year = ', year, ' then employer_rating_plan end) AS `', year, '-Rating`' ) ORDER BY year ) INTO @sql4 FROM spooner_pec;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max(case when year = ', year, ' then risk_group_number end) AS `', year, '-Gr Num`' ) ORDER BY year ) INTO @sql5 FROM spooner_pec;
SET @sql = CONCAT( 
    'SELECT policy_number AS PolicyNumber, 
    coverage_status_code As CoverageStatusCode, 
    primary_name AS PrimaryName, 
    primary_dba_name AS DBA, 
    address1 AS Address1, 
    address2 AS Address2, 
    city AS CityName, 
    state AS StateID, 
    zipcode AS ZipCode, 
    zip_plus_four AS ZipCode4, 
    business_area_code AS PhoneAreaCode, 
    business_phone AS PhoneNumber, 
    business_extension AS PhoneExtension, 
    business_contact_first_name AS FirstName, 
    business_contact_last_name AS LastName, 
    county_description AS County, ', @sql1, ', ', @sql2, ',', @sql3, ',', @sql4, ',', @sql5, ' 
    FROM spooner_pec GROUP BY policy_number');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

One of my coworkers mentioned indexing but I think the columns that are taking the longest are the ones that I am creating to pivot the data. Is there any way to index those?

Comment: I presume there is an index on `(spooner_pec.year, spooner_pec.policy_number)` or similar, right?

Comment: @rolfl There is currently only an index on the id for it to be auto_incrementing I believe.
Jamal, I apologize, I'll try to think of something more to the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your code scans the `spooner_pec` table 6 times, once each for the year-based columns, and again for the final result.

You can reduce this to just 2 times by caching the list of years in a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE GotYears (year varchar(10));

INSERT INTO GotYears
SELECT DISTINCT year
FROM spooner_pec
```

Now you have a small table with just a few years in it, instead of 3,000,000 records. You have scanned the table just once to do that too.

Now use that table to build your SQL select clauses....

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
     'max(case when year = ', year, ' then experience_rate end) AS `', year, '-Pen`' )
ORDER BY year ) INTO @sql1 FROM GotYears;
```

Having made that recommendation, though, I also recommend having an index on the `year` column which will make the scan a whole lot faster too.

The query is still ***really ugly*** ™ but that's a problem in your application and data storage.

Additionally, your final query is horrible, horrible, and horrible. A group-by query with many columns, but only grouping by the policy_id is very messy, and is MySQL specific. The values returned in the other columns are unspecified in terms of behaviour. I hope all your values in all the columns are the same or otherwise your output values are unspecified. It is a problem with your database structure too, that the data is not normalized. Why do you record the same values for the same policies in multiple records? Your database may be a data warehouse, but even then it is a bit of a mess.

You should audit your tables, and reconsider the design and normalization of your tables.

Still, if you apply the changes I suggest (add the year index, and have a single temp table for the year values), then I imagine your query will execute in about 5 seconds instead of 30.

Comment: Ya, all the data comes from a state, I don't really have control over how they have it, they just import the csv into the database and I have to change how it looks to export as a different csv.  I appreciate your advice, I will try adding the temporary table and see how that helps.  Thank you!